# PKIX path building failed :

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am developing a Spring Boot application using MS SQL server. I get this error. Can anyone please help me to rectify this.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
> establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
> Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target".
> ClientConnectionId:e89cbde3-a2c9-4164-b4d4-163b228677d9

I did not understand what is the certificate verification.

Comment: you should add trustServerCertificate=true; to your conn string